# Why IDEA import ambiguous Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IDEA 13.1

```
import x.y.ClassA;
import x.y.ClassB;
import x.y.ClassC;
import x.y.ClassD;

public class MyClass{
    //Something Else
}
```

When I want to import

> x.y.ClassE

IDEA works like this

```
import x.y.*;

public class MyClass{
    //Something Else
}
```

That's crazy!

How to set import single class rather then ambiguous import!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because of specific setting about imports in IDEA.

Go to Settings - Code Style - Java - Imports and set 'Class count to use import with '*'' to whatever value you want.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA has a setting that governs after how many imports from a single package the `*` import will be used. To configure it, go to `File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports` and change `Class count to use import with '*'` and `Names count to use static import with '*'` to some large number - say 99.